# Adding LED lights to old F150 ('90)

Tags: diodes, relay

I want to add auxiliary LED backup lights to my old F150 and strip LED lights inside the camper shell.

I want them to be switched when the ignition is in ACC or RUN position.

I want the AUX backup lights to come on when the OEM backup light switch is activated as well (but not the camper shell lights, obviously).

Rather than tapping into any OEM hot wires, I want to add a separate source circuit from the battery with an inline fuse to protect the wires.

From research I've done on the web and elsewhere, I've designed the circuit(s) and components I think I need to do this.  The diagram shows what I came up with.

The incremental wire will be 12AWG stranded copper.  I used color coding to indicate what's new and what's existing.

The red-colored box is to point out a specific question about using a diode to prevent the switched AUX backup lights from lighting when that switch is closed.  It really wouldn't matter, but it's a question to clarify for me how a diode might be used for this purpose.  If I were to use a diode here, how would I go about determining the characteristics of the part suitable for a 12VDC circuit driving the loads indicated?

I used relays for both incremental light groups but don't know if they are really needed.  The camper shell lights probably don't need the relay because, in effect, it is a redundant switch.  I put a relay in the circuit for the AUX backup lights because I want the OEM backup light switch circuit to cause the AUX lights to come on as well as when they are switched.

I would appreciate comments on my uneducated approach to this problem.  I'd especially like to know if the grounds shown are appropriate.

[image]

Comment: Do you actually need those relays? LED lamps may be low enough current you can avoid those (and the wasted power).

Comment: As I said the relay for the strip lights is probably not needed. The relay for the AUX backup lights was used to allow the OEM backup light switch to actuate the new backup lights and to allow turning the AUX backup lights on without using the OEM HEADLIGHT